# Pandas DataFrame Float Formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, formatting

I have a Pandas DataFrame of survey responses that I'm aggregating to averaged scores and outputting to HTML. My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('survey_scores.csv', header=0)
np.round(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('question_number').aggregate('mean').score).transpose(), 2).to_html()
```

It takes a DataFrame that looks kinda like this in csv...

```
response_number, question_number, score
1, 1, 3.0
1, 2, 4.0
1, 3, 4.0
2, 1, 4.0
2, 2, 4.0
2, 3, 1.0
```

And it outputs the averaged scores to an HTML table that formats the score values like this:

```
3.5, 4, 2.5
```

However, I'm trying to get the output to force each number to display two digits after the decimal point. I got it to round to two decimal points, but I'm having difficulty getting my output to format the values like this:

```
3.50, 4.00, 2.50
```

How can I get these values formatted to two decimal places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem. `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` can format floats.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('survey_scores.csv', header=0)
np.round(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('question_number').aggregate('mean').score).transpose(), 2).to_html(float_format=lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('question_number').aggregate('mean').score.transpose()\
.apply(lambda x: '{0:.2f}'.format(x))

Out[422]: 
question_number
1                  3.50
2                  4.00
3                  2.50
Name: score, dtype: object
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have `float` values, format them to 2 digits.

```
>>>　print("%.2f" % 2.5)
2.50
```

Comment: This information is not being output with print, but instead is being output to html with pandas.DataFrame.to_html()